# Add a 0 to a number given it has not already a leading 0

Tags: sql-server

How do I write in SQL server

Add a 0 to a number provided it has not already a leading 0 and has a length of 9 or 10 in total- ideally within a select statement

I have something like this, can someone please help to correct this

```
select 
[mobile] 
from tab
  WHERE 
 ( RIGHT ('0' + ([mobile] (1)), 1)
  AND LEN([mobile]) IN (9, 10))
```

Comment: Add a single `0` regardless of the string length, or pad with `0` to 9 or 10 characters?

Comment: How? I am fairly new to sql so would need some more input

Comment: Not very clear what you want here. Are you trying to figure out how to find those rows or are you trying to add a leading '0'? Are you trying to do this in the table or just a select query? Might take a peek here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have a list of phone numbers, some of them have a leading 0 and start with 057, 078, 079 but then there are a range of numbers that have only 57, 78, 79   therefore I want to add a 0 to those that are missing the 0 without adding it to every number, as otherwise I would have numbers with double zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you want here but here is my shot in the dark.

```
select NewMobile =  case when mobile not like '0%' and LEN(mobile) IN (9, 10) then '0' else '' end + mobile
from tab
```